# Python - returning something as an object instead of string

Tags: python, class, methods

I have to make a Date class and two of the methods we have to implement are nextday() and prevday(). This is my code:

```
class Date:
"""
A class for establishing a date.
"""
min_year = 1800

def __init__(self, month = 1, day = 1, year = min_year):
    """
    Checks to see if the date is real.
    """
    self.themonth = month
    self.theday = day
    self.theyear = year

def nextday(self):
    """
    Returns the date of the day after given date.
    """
    m = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)
    monthdays = [31, 29 if m.year_is_leap() else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    maxdays = monthdays[self.themonth]

    if self.theday != maxdays:
        return '{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(self.themonth, self.theday+1, self.theyear)
    elif self.theday == maxdays and self.themonth == 12:
        return '{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(1,1,self.theyear+1)
    elif self.theday == maxdays and self.themonth != 12:
        return '{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(self.themonth+1, 1, self.theyear)

def prevday(self):
    """
    Returns the date of the day before given date.
    """
    m = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)
    monthdays = [31, 29 if m.year_is_leap() else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if self.theday == 1 and self.themonth == 1:
        return Date(12, monthdays[11], self.theyear-1)
    elif self.theday == 1 and self.themonth != 1:
        return Date(self.themonth -1, monthdays[self.themonth-1], self.theyear)
    elif self.theday != 1:
        return Date(self.themonth, self.theday - 1, self.theyear)
```

As you can see, nextday returns the next day corretly, but it's a string object. Prevday, however, just returns something that looks like this: <**main**.Date object at 0x039E3270>
How can I make these functions return another date object?

Comment: Consider just using the existing `datetime` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try,

```
class Date:
"""
A class for establishing a date.
"""
min_year = 1800

def __init__(self, month = 1, day = 1, year = min_year):
    """
    Checks to see if the date is real.
    """
    self.themonth = month
    self.theday = day
    self.theyear = year

def nextday(self):
    """
    Returns the date of the day after given date.
    """
    m = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)
    monthdays = [31, 29 if m.year_is_leap() else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    maxdays = monthdays[self.themonth]

    if self.theday != maxdays:
        return Date(self.themonth, self.theday+1, self.theyear)
    elif self.theday == maxdays and self.themonth == 12:
        return Date(1,1,self.theyear+1)
    elif self.theday == maxdays and self.themonth != 12:
        return Date(self.themonth+1, 1, self.theyear)

def prevday(self):
    """
    Returns the date of the day before given date.
    """
    m = Date(self.themonth, self.theday, self.theyear)
    monthdays = [31, 29 if m.year_is_leap() else 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if self.theday == 1 and self.themonth == 1:
        return Date(12, monthdays[11], self.theyear-1)
    elif self.theday == 1 and self.themonth != 1:
        return Date(self.themonth -1, monthdays[self.themonth-1], self.theyear)
    elif self.theday != 1:
        return Date(self.themonth, self.theday - 1, self.theyear)
def year_is_leap(self):
    return True
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Date(%s,%s,%s)' % (self.themonth,self.theday,self.theyear)
```

Of course you have to implement year_is_leap().

```
>>> Date(1,1,1990).nextday()
 Date(1,2,1990)
>>> Date(1,1,1990).prevday()
Date(12,31,1989)
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is homework and OP isn't allowed to use `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

prevday is returning a new Date object, though it looks rather odd because you haven't implemented `__repr__()`.  Just change nextday to use the same `Date(...)` syntax.

Comment: Can you explain how I should be implementing __repr__()?

Comment: @flarp: `__repr__()` should return a string that looks like `Date(month, day, year)`, using `str.format()`.

Comment: I don't want to return a string, I want to return another date object

Comment: `__repr__()` is [a standard method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).  It *must* return a string.